# TideSDK IDE Support and Debugging

Tags: ide, tidesdk

Do we have any IDE support for TideSDK to build the applications.
I just installed the TideSDK, but it have plane editor and don't have any debugging options.
Is there IDE for this SDK like we have for Titanium Appcelerator.

Best Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

There is IDE  to BUild and execute the TideSDK applications.

That IDE Name is

```
TideSDK Developer
```

By using this IDE you Can Excute the Application and after finishing your application you 
can build the TideSDK Application. But there you could not Edit the code. you have to use other text editor to edit the code.

To download this go to http://www.tidesdk.org ,  there will be a button like `Download v1.3.1 beta`

just you  click it, there you can download Both TideSDK v1.3.1 beta  And TideSDK Developer tool.